# Duplicate column with different values

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to make a simple download manager, I am having trouble with adding a column with ProgressBars, it creates two columns with the same value but one has 
numeric and one has progressbar values. How can I make "Progress1" be hidden or remove it but still keep the values in "Progress2"

**Here is the main xaml**

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <!--#region Program Number -->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="#" Header="#">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProgramID}"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <!--#endregion-->


            <!--#region Program Number -->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Name" Header="Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <!--#endregion-->


            <!--#region Program Number -->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Size" Header="Size">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Size}"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <!--#endregion-->


            <!--#region Progress bar columns -->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Progress" 
                                    Header="Progress" Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>

                        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}" 
                                     Height="15"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <!--#endregion-->

            </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**Here is the Code-Behind of the programs**

```
    public class Programs : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnProperyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {


            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));

        }


        private int _programid;
        public int ProgramID
        {

            get { return _programid; }

            set
            {
                _programid = value;

                OnProperyChanged($"{nameof(ProgramID)}");
            } 
        }


        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnProperyChanged($"{nameof(Name)}");
            }
        }


        private double _size;
        public double Size
        {
            get { return _size; }
            set
            {
                _size = value;

                OnProperyChanged($"{nameof(Size)}");

            }
        }


        private double _progress;
        public double Progress
        {
            get { return _progress; }

            set
            {
                _progress = value;

                OnProperyChanged($"{nameof(Progress)}");

            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Programs> ProgramList()
        {

            ObservableCollection<Programs> programs = new ObservableCollection<Programs>
            {

                new Programs { _programid = 1, _name = "Program0", _size = 5.1, _progress = 100 },

                new Programs { _programid = 2, _name = "Program1", _size = 7.1, _progress = 36.7 },

                new Programs { _programid = 3, _name = "Program2", _size = 1.1, _progress = 44.7 },

                new Programs { _programid = 4, _name = "Program3", _size = 6.1, _progress = 88.7 },

                new Programs { _programid = 5, _name = "Program4", _size = 2.1, _progress = 89.7 },

                new Programs { _programid = 6, _name = "Program5", _size = 9.1, _progress = 68.7 },

                new Programs { _programid = 7, _name = "Program6", _size = 5.1, _progress = 98.7 },

                new Programs { _programid = 8, _name = "Program7", _size = 2.1, _progress = 59.7 },

                new Programs { _programid = 9, _name = "Program8", _size = 83.1, _progress = 18.7 }

            };

            return programs;

        }
    }
```

[Here is what it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfGHK.jpg) 
(First time posting a question so if anything is missing I'll be glad to add)

Comment: Can you show the full `DataGrid` specification? I guess you haven't set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`.

Comment: It is the full DataGrid specification or do you mean the item source biding and other ?

Comment: Let's make it easier: is the `DataGrid` property `AutoGenerateColumns` set to false?

Comment: Ok, you've updated the question and it's not.

Comment: I've set the AutoGenerateColumns property to false it does this http://i.imgur.com/L1nUU9j.jpg

Comment: how about other columns? this is not complete xaml for datagrid?

Comment: It is, do you want to see an image from the code maybe ? would  it help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the columns are getting auto generated because you have not set `AutoGeneratedColumns="false"` and `true` is the default.

When you don't set it to `false` the `DataGrid` will generate a column for each property in the assigned viewmodel.

For more information have a look at [DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx)

When you set it to false you'll only see the progress bar. So you have to specifiy the other columns like you did it with the `ProgressBar`.

You could it like this

```
<DataGrid.Columns> 
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProgramID}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Size}"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Progress" Header="Progress2">                                            
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress1}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

**edit**

Use `DataGridTextColumn` like this

```
<DataGridTextColumn SortMemberPath="ProgramID" 
                    Header="#" 
                    Binding="{Binding ProgramID}"/>
```

instead of a `TemplateColumn` when you want to show text. Much easier ;)

The problem why you won't see anything with your code is hat you only set the 
`CellEditingTemplate` and not the `CellTemplate`.

The `CellEditingTemplate` is the template which will be shown when the cell is in edit mode.

The `CellTemplate` is the one which will be shown when the cell isn't in edit mode.

When you wan't to do it your way you have to change this like

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="ProgramID" Header="#">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProgramID}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you very much I've been stuck on this for so long. I have another question if that's not a problem the progress bar values work but the text values like "ProgramID" ,"name" and  "size" don't display any value on the DataGrid

Comment: You should use the public property name in the `Binding="{Binding ....}"`. I assumed the properties are ProgramId, Name and Size. If they are different you have to change the binding. If it's not working please add the code of your `Programs` class in your question.

Comment: The properties are set to public I am using MVVM so it might be that I am using it wrong where

Comment: Thank you very much you've been a huge help